# Dynamic redirect in php other websites automatically

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a website I want to redirect it to some other page like

```
www.website.com/abcd.html
```

To redirect like

```
www.website.com/1/abcd.html
www.website.com/2/abcd.html
```

similarly 3 4 5 •••    based on time and conditions website redirect to any other website  of that how can I create it using php

Example 1st user go redirect to

```
www.website.com/5/abcd.html
```

2nd user to

```
www.website.com/3/abcd.html
```

this redirect should be made automatically by server

Comment: That doesn't sound so bad. What have you coded so far?

Comment: You just send back a 303 redirect with the `Location` header pointing to the redirect URL.

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting with PHP is typically best done by [manipulating headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```php
header( "Location: abcd.html" );
```

This causes the browser to redirect to the target file/domain. Just make sure you set this before you've output anything to the browser, otherwise you'll get a *headers already sent* message.

Sending individual users to different endpoints should be handled by a [load-balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29). It distributes traffic over a cluster of servers to keep the strain down on each one individually.

That being said, you could construct your header url conditionally, or [randomly](http://www.php.net/rand):

```php
$index = rand( 1, 5 ); // Generates a random number, 1 to 5.
header( "Location: /$index/abcd.html" );
```

Each endpoint will have a 20% chance of getting hit, for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking how to set location header to redirect? [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
Or you will balancing your load?

In php you must handle a counter and store them, for example, in Databse or a file.

```
<?php
$visitor = ... (compute visitor number)
header('Location: http://www.website.com/'.$visitor.'/abcd.html');
?>
```